# Algebra Troubles. $y^{1-\rho}=x \rightarrow y =x^{\rho}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While reading some old lecture notes, I found "NB: $\frac{1}{1-\rho}=\rho$ " where $\rho \in (0,1)$. This was used to simplify $y^{1-\rho}=x \rightarrow y =x^{\rho}$.

I've been trying to make sense of it, but I can't see how it isn't wrong. For example, $\frac{1}{1-0.3}=\frac{1}{0.7} \neq 0.3$.

Any ideas what is going on?

[image: The goal is to calculate the Marshallian demand functions]

Comment: Can you please share the link to the lecture notes?

Comment: If one *assumes* that $\frac{1}{1-\rho} = \rho$ then from $y^{1-\rho} =x$ one can deduce $y=x^\rho$.  But there are no such $\rho$, though.  Seems weird.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-\rho}=\rho$ doesn't even have *real* solutions (the solutions are the non-real cube roots of $-1$), so the relation doesn't hold for *any* $\rho\in(0,1)$. Without further context from the lecture notes, it's impossible for anyone to tell where the error (or simple misunderstanding) lies.

Comment: Maybe there is a different variable on the RHS: $\frac{1}{1-\rho}=t \implies 1-\rho=\frac{1}{t} \implies y^\frac{1}{t}=x, y=x^t$

Comment: @PNDas https://imgur.com/a/XwG3CFR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if $\frac{1}{1-\rho} = \rho$ then we can multiply both sides by $1-\rho$ to get $1 =(1-\rho) \rho.$

Then take the equation $y^{1-\rho}=x$ and raise both sides to the $\rho$ power to get

$$y^{(1-\rho)\rho} = x^\rho.$$

By the equation above, the exponent on $y$ equals $1$.

If you solve the $\rho$ equation, you get $\rho = (1+\sqrt{3}i)/2$, which is a cube root of $-1$.  I wouldn't expect complex numbers in this context, however.

Comment: Agreed, especially since if complex numbers *were* allowed the exponential things wouldn't be well-defined anymore.